# How to preview font in-line with Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

In Microsoft Word, you can preview how each font looks very quickly by flipping through the fonts with the arrow keys. But the rendered font appears in a 'Preview' window.

Is there a way to quickly flip through the fonts and **see the preview *in-line* in my Word document?**

I want to see how various fonts work with the layout, fonts, and graphics already in the document. Every formatting dialog I am familiar with (Fonts, Styles, Reveal Formatting, etc) require you to close the dialog box (click '`OK`) to see how the font looks in the document. Very tedious. Is there a formatting technique that will allow me to flip through a bunch of fonts and see them in my document?

I am currently working with Windows XP, Word 2003 but I can switch to Word 2007.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Live Preview](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Word-for-new-users-CACE0FD8-EED9-4AA2-B3C6-07D39895886C#__toc252541096) is the name for that feature, and it's available in Word 2007.  It goes beyond just font changes and will show you what any other formatting changes will look like for the currently selected text before you actually make them.

Comment: You link is broken. `Sorry, the page you’re looking for can’t be found.`